# Trouble passing PHP variables to JS using "attach"

Tags: 7, javascript

Module-noob here. I've seen plenty of threads on this topic in general but haven't found any concerning use of "attach." I'm working on a fairly simple module that applies some JavaScript to every page on the site. It was working fine, but pareview told me not to use drupal_add_js() in hook_page_build(), instructing me to use attach instead. I can't figure out how to get my PHP variables over to my JS using this method.

The JS file itself is loading, but it is not receiving the data from the PHP variables. From what I have read, I understand that the following is the way to accomplish what I am trying to do, but obviously I've got something wrong somewhere. Here is my code:

**mymodule.module:**

```
function mymodule_page_build() {

  $page['#attached']['js'] = array(
    array(
      'data' => drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/mymodule.js',
      'options' => array(
        'preprocess' => TRUE,
        'every_page' => TRUE,
      ),
    ),
    array(
      'data' => array(
        'mymodule_status' => variable_get('mymodule_status', 0),
      ),' => 'setting',
    ),
  );
}
```

**mymodule.js:**

```
(function ($) {
  "use strict";
  Drupal.behaviors.myModule = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      var moduleStatus = Drupal.settings.mymodule.mymodule_status;
      var milk = 'milk';
      $(document).ready(function () {
        // Debug:
        console.log('first');      // works
        console.log(milk);         // works
        console.log(moduleStatus); // Says mymodule is undefined
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Thank you for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out there were two problems.

First, I needed to be using `function mymodule_page_build(&$page)`. I was originally leaving out the `&$page`.

Second, it turns out that to use `#attached` on the page itself, you have to access the 'content' property of the page.

So, instead of:

`$page['#attached']['js']`

It should be:

`$page['content']['#attached']['js']`

Answer (score 1):

Have a look on this [page](https://www.drupal.org/node/304258)

For getting the value of a variable that has been set in the module you have to use like this `Drupal.settings.<modulename>.<variablename>`

In your module file

```
function mymodule_page_build() {
  $status = variable_get('mymodule_status', 0);
  drupal_add_js(array('MODULENAME' => array('mymodule_status' => $status)), 'setting'); 

  $page['#attached']['js'] = array(
    array(
      'data' => drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/mymodule.js',
      'options' => array(
        'preprocess' => TRUE,
        'every_page' => TRUE,
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

So in your case it should be

`Drupal.settings.mymodule.mymodule_status`

Comment: Hmm, it's telling me that Drupal.settings.mymodule is undefined. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: have you tried Drupal.settings.mymodule.<yourvariablename> this? not to mention please clear cache once.

Comment: Yes I tried Drupal.settings.mymodule.myvariable, as well as Drupal.settings.mymodule['myvariable'] just to be safe. Each time it said it couldn't get property 'myvariable' of undefined. So then I tested it out in the console with just Drupal.settings.mymodule, and it's just returning undefined. I also checked out the page you linked, but it doesn't seem to have instructions for using the attach method. Edit: Also, yes I've cleared the cache each time.

Comment: Then I doubt on your module, variable is not assigning to the js

Comment: It looks like it isn't recognizing Drupal.settings.mymodule at all. Am I maybe not attaching it correctly?

Comment: my answer updated. please have a look now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38341/discussion-between-rrr45-and-nagarjuna).